# retrieve id from single table and insert it into another table

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a vb project and I am stuck at these queries.

```
cmd1.CommandText = "select party_id from tbl_party_data where ppan=lblpan.Text"
cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_party_record (party_id, ward) values ('" & "value of cmd1.comandtext" & "','" & txtward.Text & "')"
```

I have inserted data successfully in `tbl_party_data` table and now i want to insert data into the `tbl_party_record` table using foreign key.
but I don't know how to write these queries in vb.net.
`tbl_party_data` is a primary key table and `tbl_party_record` is a foreign key table.
and `party_id` is used as primary key in 1st table and as a foreign key in 2nd table.
So could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **ExecuteScalar** to return a value of the Key:

```
Dim partyId As Integer
cmd1.CommandText = "select party_id from tbl_party_data where ppan=lblpan.Text"
partyId = cmd1.ExecuteScalar()
cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_party_record (party_id, ward) values ('" & partyId & "','" & txtward.Text & "')"
```

Comment: thnx to all guys for provide me solution. your solution works for me...@Alexandre Nascimento

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in single sql command as below.You should use parameters to protect from the sql injection:

```
   Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=TEst//TEst;Initial Catalog=cMind_ProgramGuide;Persist Security Info=False;")
   Dim strsql As String = "Insert into tbl_party_record (party_id, ward) select party_id ,@ward from tbl_party_data where ppan=@ppan"
   Dim Command As New SqlCommand(strsql, connection)
   Command.Parameters.Add("@ppan", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lblpan.Text
   Command.Parameters.Add("@ward", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtward.Text
   connection.Open()
   Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
   connection.Close()
```

This should work for you perfectly.